# Twitter Stream Error

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am trying to harvest tweets from twitter with twitter API. I am getting an error in twitterStream statement as shown below: How do i solve it.

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import time

ckey = 'serhsrtjhath'
csecret = 'sdfhszdjsrztj'

atoken = 'aerhyaetjsjk'
asecret = 'srtjsrkisk'

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
def on_data(self, data):
        try:        
        #print data
        saveFile = open('tweetdb.csv', 'a')
        saveFile.write(data)
        saveFile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close()
        return True
        except BaseException, e:
        print 'failed ondata,',str(e)
        time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, l)
twitterStream.filter(track=["Paris"])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_data.py", line 34, in <module>
    twitterStream = Stream(auth, l)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Note: I use Python 2.7.

Comment: please set you indendation

Comment: Sitz Blogz, what is your question?

Comment: @Robᵩ I want the error to go. I did look into few examples around but every where i see the same way given and i guess its only me getting such error.

Comment: is that all of the code or just a snapshot of a larger file? I'm only asking because your code is pretty much the example from the tweepy github page and which is working (I just tested it). Do you perhaps have another import named `Stream` in your code?

Comment: @tttthomasssss Yes this is full code and yes it is same as given in github. This is my very first code for harvesting twitter data. I am getting the error.

Comment: @SitzBlogz try passing an options dict to the `Stream` constructor and see if that improves/changes things, sth like `twitterStream = Stream(auth, l, {'snooze_time': 0.3})`

Comment: This does not give errors nor does give any output